# Using MoveIt2 to plan a smooth path consisted of several discretized points to control a UR5e robot

Tags: ros2, moveit, universal-robots, joint-trajectory-controller, ros2-control

I would like to generate a "smooth" trajectory in space, and plan it using Moveit2 (along with ROS2 humble) in order to make a UR5e robot drive these points.

I am aware that I need to discretize this trajectory into several points.

My guess is that I would need the MoveIt2 path planner to compute the joint positions, and I would send these to the joint trajectory controller of ros_control.

I tried to google around but could not find a similar implementation.

I would appreciate any help, or any road map that I should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to generate a "smooth" trajectory in space, and plan it using Moveit2 (along with ROS2 humble) in order to make a UR5e robot drive these points.

Usually, you would make use of the [`MoveGroupInterface`](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html), which provides a C++ API to interface with your robot. If you take a look at the file [move_group_interface.h](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h), you will find a couple of functions that will help you setup and plan for poses with your robot.

The general order of usage is as follows:

- setup MoveGroupInterface to accept the robot description and the SRDF *(look at the tutorial for a clearer explanation)*
- Set the planning parameters using the [`setPlannerParams`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/0807cb254d01abdc4f60247d2c322e1aead71d35/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L205) function
- Set a target for the robot. You can either use [`setJointValueTarget`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/0807cb254d01abdc4f60247d2c322e1aead71d35/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L412C3-L412C71), or [`setPoseTarget`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/0807cb254d01abdc4f60247d2c322e1aead71d35/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L562) depending on your use-case.
- Generate a [`plan`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/0807cb254d01abdc4f60247d2c322e1aead71d35/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L712C50-L712C50) for the robot.
- Once happy with the generated plan, you want to [`execute`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/0807cb254d01abdc4f60247d2c322e1aead71d35/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h#L747) it.

**NOTE:** In the general context of MoveIt2, "plan" just constructs a trajectory, that the robot needs to follow. When you want the robot to follow the generated trajectory, you want to call the "execute" function.

> My question is: how should I provide these points (which would be in Cartesian coordinates) so that they would be used to create the respective joint coordinates and be sent to ros_control?

You should ideally not be putting in a trajectory by hand, as it leads to augmentation of human error. What you should do instead, is use `setPoseTargets`, or in your case, I think you would like to use `setJointValueTargets`, plan for these joint values, store the plan, do some post-processing if necessary, and then send it off to execute.

Normally, the UR5 should have some moveit_config file pertaining to ros2_control, this YAML should take care of passing the output of the MoveIt-generated trajectory over to the ros2_control side of things. IIRC, for the simplest operation, there is a [JointTrajectoryController](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver/blob/fcc9d3602e12d5e73835f42275ba8c1a753a9d7b/ur_moveit_config/config/controllers.yaml#L3) used, which takes in the generated plan and sends it over to the dedicated robot controller.

Hope this helps to make things clearer !

Answer (score 1):

Welcome at RSE.

What do you mean with "smooth", do you have certain constraints or limits you want to consider?

I haven't used MoveIt2 a lot, but have you tried to configure the [trajectory processing](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/time_parameterization/time_parameterization_tutorial.html) (and optional Ruckig smoother)?

joint_trajectory_controller is default in MoveIt2 setups. It interpolates in between the points of your trajectory message, see [the docs for some details](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/joint_trajectory_controller/doc/trajectory.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

For now I am not interested in the constraints and limitations for the motion of the robot.

My question is: how should I provide these points (which would be in Cartesian coordinates) so that they would be used to create the respective joint coordinates and be sent to ros_control? For example, should I put them in a yaml file?

I have not encountered an example or any tutorial for this yet.

Comment: Have you seen the tutorials in the MoveIt docs? [Integration with a New Robot](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/examples.html#integration-with-a-new-robot), especially the section of "low level controllers"